# Objective c. Login user using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, storyboard, segue

I have an storyboard with three view controllers, the init view with a button Init, the login view controller and the list view controller. When I click in the button init in the first view controller, I would like to verify whether the user logged in in order to switch to the login view or to the list view. How could I implement this using segues (segue conditionals??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLoggedIn"];      
NSString *headingStoryboardID = isLoggedIn ? @"YourAlreadyLoggedInVC_ID" : @"YourLoginVC_ID";

if([headingStoryboardID isEqualToString:@"YourAlreadyLoggedInVC_ID"]) {
     AlreadyLoggedInClass *vc1 = (AlreadyLoggedInClass *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourAlreadyLoggedInVC_ID"];
     [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
     LoginViewController *vc2 = (LoginViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourLoginVC_ID"];
     [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

OBS: Ugly and uncompiled code but hope the concept gets across.

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENT**
To perform a push segue you call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
```

instead.

Comment: Hi Filip, why when I use presentViewController I lost the navigationController (Top navigation)?

Comment: @ErnestoRodriguez presentViewController will perform a modal segue whereas you apparently want to perform a push segue. Se my edit!

Answer (score 1):

You can Store your login value in user default when user login like this
in LOginViewController

```
-(void) doLogin
{
NSString * str = @"Loged In";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:str forKey:@"login"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And in first view controller check whether this NSdefault value is nil or not.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userLogIn = [defaults objectForKey:@"login"];


    if (userLogIn.length !=0) {
        //then user Loged in
    }else
    {
       //then user not Loged in
    }
```

This code is just example you can change it acording to your need.

Comment: Hi Dilip, thanks for the answer but my doubt is how manipulate the segues in the storyboard, because I have only one segue that could call to two possible views (login or list).